# RTL words mixed with English words in Comments/Messages

Tags: html, css, user-interface, comments, right-to-left

I knew months ago, that making your UI available for RTL (Right-To-Left) Languages is related to CSS layout.

But what if your UI layout is just available for English, and you have a users who write comments or send messages that have a mixed words of RTL and English. It appears very bad.

I would like to understand what is the reason for this, and what is the technical part of the project that is responsible for this, and how to solve it if it possible.

You can point me to just keywords or articles to read about this points.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need `dir="rtl"` on the elements that are in the RTL language. Check out [this guy's website](http://www.i18nguy.com/markup/right-to-left.html) for a much better response than mine.